# Setting the attribute of an HTML tag with EJS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, ejs

On my express server I'm rendering a page with data as follows:

```
app.get('/people/:personID', function (req, res) {
  res.render("people/profile", {person: req.person });
});
```

In my profile.ejs file I can access the data in an ejs tag like so: `<p><%= person.name %></p>`

I can't figure how to change an attribute of an html tag to the value stored in this object though.

This doesn't work: `<img id="my_img" src=<%= person.picture %> alt="">`
or this: `$("#my_img").attr("src", <%= person.picture %>);`

Also, if there's a better way to pass this document to the html page and access it I'm all ears(or eyes in this case). Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should add quotes: `<img id="my_img" src="<%= person.picture %>" alt="">`

Comment: This worked! I didn't try that. I assumed it would be treated as a literal string

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to include string values within quotes.

In html:

```
<img id="my_img" src="<%= person.picture %>" alt="">
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#my_img").attr("src", "<%= person.picture %>");
```

Comment: And in case you want to fill a JS call like onclick, but your data may contain single apostrophes, you can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) passed via e.g. `onclick="someCall(this)" data-something="<%= someValue %>"`, which in the receiving function can be read via `passedThisElement.dataset.something`.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I did the same here but it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659225/displaying-default-value-in-html-form-from-mysql-using-node-js