# Displaying Default value in HTML form from MySQL using node.js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, ejs

I am having a scenario where I have to display a form and rather than taking input, I have to display some value extracted from database using nodejs. Below is the expected outcome

[image]

So, I wrote the following code

`confirm.ejs`

```
<form>
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= ticket.Fname %>" id="fname" readonly>
</form>
```

`js` but I believe it is correct

```
router.get("/confirm",function(req,res){
    db.query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE Ticket=?",[variabled4],function(err, results, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('confirm', { title: 'ticket info', ticket: results});
    });
});
```

So, I think the problem is in `value = "<%= ticket.Fname %>` and the whole form is displayed but with empty fields. (`Fname` is a column in `details` table with hello as value, not to be confused as a typo of fname)

Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: the mdn website suggests `HTMLInputElement` but I don't know how to use that

Comment: `sequelize` Raw Queries should return an array as response. Check if you need to  extract ticket from it (`{ title: 'ticket info', ticket: results[0]}`).

Comment: @Daniel thank you very much. At first, I thought you were selecting the specific column in the array but then I understood that you were selecting the array itself. I will try again using this edit.

Comment: @Daniel thanks the question was solved and there was no issue with the ejs inside html tag that I thought. You can post an answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sequelize `Raw Queries` returns an array as response. You should check if the array is not empty and extract the `ticket` for `results[0]`

See: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

Here a small snippet (Handel the "ticket not found" as you see fit)

```
router.get("/confirm",function(req,res){
    db.query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE Ticket=?",[variabled4],function(err, results, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
         // on "results.length == 0" handle "ticket not found" flow

        let ticket = results[0];
        res.render('confirm', { title: 'ticket info', ticket: ticket});
    });
});
```